# RestKit - delete objects that are not returned

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I am looking for a way to delete objects that exist locally in CoreData, but are no longer returned from the server's JSON response. I have looked at [Fetch Request Blocks and Deleting Orphaned Objects](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html), but in my case the objects does not have parent, so I think that it will not work for me.
In my case I do not want to delete orphaned objects, because they never had a parent. Did I misunderstood the concept described in the example? Is there a way to do a similar fetch request that will gather all local records and compare them agains the server-returned ones, or I will have to do it manually after RestKit is done with the mapping?

EDIT:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:@"http://example.com"];
[manager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
    RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"/api/articles.json"];

    NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
    BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];
    if (match) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Article"];
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"articleID IN %@", ARTICLEIDS]
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES] ];
        return fetchRequest;
    }

    return nil;
}];
```

Is the following example correct? If so, the problem I face here is how to get the `ARTICLEIDS` from the server response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you misunderstood the meaning of `orphan`. In this case it doesn't mean that the object doesn't have a parent, it simply means that the object wasn't returned in the most recent request. This feature of RestKit does exactly what you're looking for - search for all objects in the data store, remove the ones just received, delete the remainder.

Comment: Do you have or need `ARTICLEIDS`? I don't know, that is dependent on your usage and request. Do you specify an id when making the request?

Comment: Better stated, is there an id in the URL path? If not then you can't use it even if you do pass it (in the request body).

Comment: I do not have an ID in the URL, my json path is like http://example.com/api/articles.json and it returns all current articles. At this step I need to delete the ones that are not returned from the server.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I can just make a fetchRequest without predicate, this way it will return all articles and then RestKit will take care for the rest, right?

Comment: So just remove the predicate and sort descriptor from the fetch request so it finds all of the Article entities in the data store

Comment: Note you should probably also use `pathMatcherWithPattern:@"api/articles.json"` and put the slash on the end of your base URL - this should be the model you follow for all path patterns